# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Running low-graphics mode

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

This happens when I try to install/update the Nvidia driver on my system using cuda_8.0.61.2_linux. 
[Prompt dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI0Ob.png)

Comment: To anyone coming here from Google or SO search, the more complete canonical Q&A is at AskUbuntu: [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/q/141606/727997).

Answer (score 10):

This could be caused by conflicting x11 libs. Some of you might also experience similar issue on a different or older version of Ubuntu.
[Prompt dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI0Ob.png)

Perform Ctrl+Alt+F1 then a console will be displayed.
Enter your credentials...

(1) You need to reset the "lightdm" with the following:

```
sudo rm /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo ucf -p /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

(2) Then re-install "recommended driver" nvidia (can be found on your system current nvidia drivers)

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

You will see something like:

```
...
...
driver  :  nvidia-384 - distro non-free recommended
...
```

You will use the nvidia specified as recommended which is on this example is *nvidia-384*
Finally, perform:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-384
```

And reboot the system.

Comment: I found I didn't even need to touch lightdm - just installing an older driver got my desktop back.  Go raibh maith agat!